# Why I not use $rootScope variable in $mdDialog Template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I working with a Project and now I use $mdDialog directive. I declare a base url in $rootScope variable & it's work perfect with template but not with $mdDialog template. Why get this problem...

```
$mdDialog.show({
          template: "<md-dialog>{{static_path}}</md-dialog>",
          controller : function($scope, $mdDialog, HttpService){
      }
  });
```

Comment: I think $mdDialog is having another module , use it with service

Comment: but when i alert in controller. rootScope variable accessed...

Comment: $mdDialog is defined another module and you have injected that module i suppose so try to console the value of $rootscope in show() method of $mdDialog

Comment: I know $mdDialog is a directive of another module. and i use show() method of $mdDialog. but my question is $rootScope variable access in $mdDialog Controller but not in $mdDialog Template. why?

Comment: ok is it static_path variable is $rootscope variable

Comment: yes... and it's work with another template

Comment: please post code of md-dialog directive

Comment: Sorry this code is very lengthy. basically not any $scope variable show into template. if I use ng-bind="myname" it work perfect but when i use {{myname}} it's not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88998/discussion-between-shubham-nigam-and-sandeep).

Answer (score 4):

You should add

```
scope:$scope,
preserveScope:true,
```

to your `$mdDialog.show` options.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I hope your answer gets marked as solved.